# cant spot the syntax error in django views

Tags: python, django, formset

hi guys i am having trouble in finding the syntax error in my Django views.I am trying to create the view of creating a post by a user with the help of inline formset as code given below.But the view is throwing error in case of following below:

iam getting the error indicator right below the (:)

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked the indentations but can't spot the error spot.can you find it out if you are reading it ?

```
 #views.py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms
from .models import *
@login_required
def post(request):
    form = forms.PostForm()
    formset =forms.AnswerInlineFormSet(queryset=models.Answer.objects.none()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.PostForm(request.POST)    
        formset=forms.ImageInlineFormSet(request.POST,request.
                              FILES,queryset=Images.objects.none())
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            images = formset.save(commit=False)
            for image in images:
                image.post = post
                image.save()
            messages.success(request,'Post added.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/feeds')
     return render(request,'usersubmit/post_create.html',{'form'= form,'formset' = formset,})
```

here is the form for the view:

```
 #forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Post,Images
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'synopsis','category','tags' )


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('image','body', )

ImageFormset= forms.modelformset_factory(
    models.Images,
     form=ImageForm,
)       

ImageInlineFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
      models.Post,
    models.Images,
    extra=2,
    fields = ('image','body', ),
    formset=ImageFormset,
    min_num=1,
)
```

can you guys please review my code?

Comment: As always, it's a missing `)` on the previous line.

Comment: thanks you so much. that was silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need add `)`

```
formset =forms.AnswerInlineFormSet(queryset=models.Answer.objects.none()
```

to

```
formset =forms.AnswerInlineFormSet(queryset=models.Answer.objects.none())
#                                                                      ^^^
```